# how to merge-union sorted data sets without another sort

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to get an efficient data feed for a downstream process, but the generated query plan tries to cache the entire output before passing me anything.

My input data is a table that has:

```
ID,Attribute1,Attribute2,Attribute3,otherID
- Clustered index on ID(not unique) 
- OtherID is unique)

about 10M rows, output query has up to 50 rows per ID, but 7 is typical
```

there are secondary tables which contain 0-5 attributes per otherID with a structure like

```
Attribute4Table:
id4(PK),OtherID, Attribute4 

Attribute5Table:
id5(PK),OtherID, Attribute5
```

and the desired output is:

```
ID Dimension Value
4 'Attribute1' w
4 'Attribute4' x
4 'Attribute4' y
4 'Attribute3' z
5 'Attribute2' a
5 'Attribute3' b
5 'Attribute1' c
```

The by current query looks like:
    there is a clustered index on ##quoteHistory(id)

```
select * from ( 
select ID,  'Attribute1' Dimension, cast(thing1 as varchar(400)) Value from ##quoteHistory
  UNION  ALL 
select  ID,  'Attribute2' Dimension, cast(thing2 as varchar(400)) Value from ##quoteHistory
  UNION ALL
... couple of other similer clauses, 'Dimension' is unique
) x order by ID   where Value is not null
```

output requirements: all rows for a given ID are output together (downstream application consumes the data ID group by ID group, and the cost of processing this data is substantially more than the query).

Problem: when it (correctly) detects it can use a merge-union, sql server unnecessarily pre-sorts the data..

[image: query plan including value]

by "unnecessary" if you remove "value" from the query you get the query plan i'm expecting, which is a stream output with no blocking components:

```
select * from ( 
    select ID,  'Attribute1' Dimension from ##quoteHistory
      UNION  ALL 
    select  ID,  'Attribute2' Dimension from ##quoteHistory
      UNION ALL
    ... couple of other similer clauses
) x order by ID
```

[image: query plan selecting ID and Dimension only]

Question:
How do i coerce the first query to produce the second plan, as that plan does produce the output ordering that i'm interested in.

edit:
In the full data set, other tables are sometimes joined onto ##quoteHistory in a 1:many relationship to pick up multiple values for that dimension.

Comment: IMHO, it will be far simpler ,if your throw table structure and sample data and desire output.I think your query is wrong.Number of rows in your table ?index ? Normally "coerce" part is done using "hint" or rewriting query."Hint" is not advisable.

Comment: Please reduce your query as much as possible while the effect still appears. Then show us the full query for both cases together with full XMLs of both actual execution plans and DDL of the table(s) and indexes used in the query. You can use https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ or pastebin.com for the plan XMLs.